# Excel Macro Issue Copying and Pasting from base workbook to current workbook (and sheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wanting to automate a process I did on a report by copying and pasting both text and formulas from a base file to recurring new reports. I'm having trouble with this code

```
Workbooks("2020_05_11_14_49_06J615101_2020a.txt").Worksheets("2020_05_11_14_49_06J615101_2020").Range("AB1:AI1").Copy ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AB1")
```

This is just the text copy, after this issue is solved, I need to copy and paste the formulas

*Edit 5/15/20* A .txt file can indeed be opened in excel, it just is loaded in as data when opening the program. The problem is that when automating, Excel doesn't like the above string when running the macro.

Comment: Are you trying to open a text file?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually trying to solve. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Instead of `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AB1")` try `ActiveSheet.Range("AB1")`  Which workbook is active when this runs?

Comment: @Variatus Excel doesn't seem to have any issue with 'Workbooks("2020_05_11_14_49_06J615101_2020a.txt")' when running the macro. The problem lies somewhere between 'copy' and 'ActiveSheet'

Comment: @TimWilliams the workbook being pasted into is active when this runs, and there is only one sheet in the workbook. The copied from workbook is not open at all

Comment: "The copied from workbook is not open at all" - are you opening it before running the line you posted?  If not you will need to do that.  If Yes then posting more of your code might clarify things.